# How to use scoped packages in NPM workspaces?

Tags: npm, npm-workspaces

My top `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@foo/eslint-config": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=7.0.0",
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "packageManager": "npm@8.18.0"
}
```

and I have a package in `packages/@foo/eslint-config`.

However, when I do `npm install`, I get an error saying that `@foo/eslint-config` is not in the registry.

I am assuming that I have either wrong directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

The package should have gone directly to `packages/eslint-config` directory.

The package name still needs to have the scope, i.e. `@foo/eslint-config`.

It appears that workspaces do not use the same convention of nesting scoped packages under a sub-directory as `node_modules` do.

It also appears that the folder name has no significance, as long as it is directly in the directory defined in `workspaces` configuration and has the correct package name.

Alternatively, you can also just update your workspaces configuration to read from `packages/@foo/*`.